# How to create number mask using type "number"?

Tags: javascript

The code below validates, when typing, a phone number pattern:

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});


<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"/>
```

When replacing `type="text"` with `type="number"`, the algorithm does not work correctly. My intention is to make the user's keyboard open with the option of just numbers while the above code works exactly as it is. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the user on a mobile device (with a mobile keyboard) or is it a user on a computer?

Comment: You will need to have all digits entered sequentially without spaces or special character.

Comment: Better use [`<input type="tel">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel), or not?

Comment: @PM77-1 were you answering my question?

Comment: Custom masks will not work on non-text type inputs.

Comment: @SvenEberth Your answer solved the problem. I can't believe it was such a simple thing. I'm a beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unsurprising that HTML type="number" doesn't work for a phone#.

You really have two separate problems:

1. You'd like to validate a phone# input field.  A regex could be a good solution.
2. You'd also like to filter out invalid characters as the user fills out the input field.

There are many options; each with its own pros/cons.

For starters, you might consider using [<input type="tel">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)

Here are several other ideas to consider:

- [How to force Input field to enter numbers only using JavaScript ?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-force-input-field-to-enter-numbers-only-using-javascript/)
- [JavaScript: HTML Form - Phone Number validation](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no way to add a maks to number input with characters like `()`
but you could add `inputmode="numeric"` this will force mobiles to open numbers keyboard

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" inputmode="numeric" />
```

or you could use the `pattern` attribute and set it allow to allow digits only like this

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" pattern="\d*" />
```